# Getting the League Value in the Select Statement (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this where i have a query to get the teams and filtering them by their league. My problem is that in the the console.log of the following code the data is being shown correctly but in the SELECT statement it's not working as it's not showing anything in the dropdown. When i do it hardcoded the SELECT statement works fine. Any idea what might be the problem. Thanks

**Code**

```
$league = '';

if(isset($_POST['selected'])):
   $league = $_POST['selected'];
endif;

$home_team = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE competition = :league");

echo "<script>console.log($league)</script>";
$home_team->execute([ ':league' => $league ]);
```

**Fetching Teams**

```
 <?php
    while ($row = $home_team->fetchAll()) 
   {
       $hometeamlogo = $row['logo'];
       $hometeamstadium = $row['stadium'];
       echo "<option value='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode( $hometeamlogo )."' data-stadium='$hometeamstadium'>" . $row['team_name'] . "</option>";
   }
 ?>
```

**AJAX Call**

```
 $('#input_competition').on('change', function () {
         var selectedLeague = $('#input_competition').find(":selected").text();
           
         $.ajax({
            url: 'queries/view_fixtures_queries.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'selected' : selectedLeague},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
       });
```

Comment: 1. You are open to SQL injections 2. You have no error handling 3. $league may have no value 4. You need to learn about server-side and client0side programming as your order of execution is clearly not correct

Comment: The value is being retrieved in the console.log

Comment: If your problem is that it isn't _outputting_ correctly; maybe it would be helpful if you showed that code?

Comment: My question was if the code i gave is correct in terms of the SELECT statement since in the console.log it is being outputted correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Cause if i hard-code the WHERE clause with the league it would work correctly

Comment: Are you using `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: Im using PDO...

Comment: To confirm: if you change ":league" with the actual value... It works? **And** that the `console` shows the correct value for `$league`?

Comment: @Strawberry the question has been edited to use bound variables; previously it used `".$league."` in place of `:league`

Comment: @Steven Oh yeah; I missed that when reviewing the edits :-$

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['selected']` is what is being posted?

Comment: Yes exactly and the console shows the correct value

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this works just fine for me...

```
<?php
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS teams;

CREATE TABLE teams
(team_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,team VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
,competition VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO teams VALUES
(1,'Arsenal','Premiership'),
(2,'Chelsea','Premiership'),
(3,'Crystal Palace','Premiership'),
(4,'QPR','Championship'),
(5,'Greenwich Borough','Isthmian');
*/


require('path/to/pdo/connect.ion');

$league = '';

$_POST['selected'] = 'Premiership';

if(isset($_POST['selected'])):
   $league = $_POST['selected'];
endif;

//'$pdo' is my connection object
$home_team = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE competition = :league");

echo "<script>console.log($league)</script>";
$home_team->execute([ ':league' => $league ]);

$data  = $home_team->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: It works fine like this but i'm doing this part `$data  = $home_team->fetchAll();` in another php file which was working fine before i included the WHERE clause

Comment: I included this part in the Question where i'm fetching the teams data

Comment: Also i added the AJAX call im making in the same file as the fetching teams